# How to store open id's in database?

Tags: mysql, facebook, openid

I am working on the login system of my next website, and I want to integrate the possibility to log in with a facebook account (and in future probably other openID providers).

I am curious what is the best way to store openID's.

My idea is:

```
id: INT, AUTO_INCREMENT
user_id: INT
network: varchar(2) (fb - Facebook, tw - Twitter, etc.) (2 bytes)
network_id: INT (4 bytes)
```

But are really all network id's INTEGERs? 
Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it causing a performance issue yet?

Comment: No. I just want to make sure my database keys are as small as possible, and if can I store the network_id as a number int/bigint?

Comment: If it's not causing a performance issue, then don't worry about it. Your users will not care if they wait **0.290 seconds** for your query to run because the network ID column was 16 bytes or if they wait **only 0.234 seconds** because the network ID column was optimized to 4 bytes. However, they will care if they don't have the ability to login (in crude terms), so get the login page up and running and don't worry about the performance until you need to scale.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about twitter, but userID in facebook is integer, so far the longest i've seen was 15 numbers, so you'd probably need BIGINT

Comment: You are right. Facebook id's must stored as BIGINT (it was specified in the old facebook api documentation).